# Can I assign a class enum based on a private/protected member?

Tags: c++, class, enums, field, member

I have a class and need to make the size of one of its protected members publicly available.

I cannot make the field public and don't want to introduce a new field, so I am trying to introduce an enum and assign it to the size of the field, like so:

```cpp
class MyObject
{
  public:
    enum
    {
        myFieldSize = sizeof(myField),
    };
  protected:
    uint8_t myField;
}
```

However my compiler tells me that it can't find a declaration for "myField". Is this the expected behavior? I have other public functions that access myField, why is the enum seemingly unable to do so?

Comment: You can write a public member function like getFieldSize() and return the sizeof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those instances where the order of what you have in your class matters: `myField` does not exist at the point `sizeof(myField)` is reached.

A workaround is to have `uint8_t myField;` above the `enum`.

Comment: I'd say that it is more usual for order of declarations to matter even within class. The exception is that member function definitions can refer to member declarations after them

Comment: @eerorika: 6 of one and 1/2 dozen of the other methinks. Anyway I've tinned "unusual".

Comment: Somedays, I wish C++ was a two-pass language.

Answer (score 4):

The name myField is not declared when it is used in the enum declaration. Exchange the data members declarations like

```
class MyObject
{
  protected:
    uint8_t myField;
  public:
    enum
    {
        myFieldSize = sizeof(myField),
    };
};
```